# Why API actually called when run unit test of a function used Coroutine to call API with networkBoundResource in Android?

Tags: android, api, unit-testing, mocking, kotlin-coroutines

I have an issue in unit test for a function used Coroutine to call API with networkBoundResource.
The issue is when run the test the API actually called, although it's supposed to return the expected response such as I determined in this line: `whenever(mfSDKPaymentRepository.sendPayment(request)).thenReturn(expectedResponse)`

**This is the function want to test:**

```
fun callSendPayment(
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope? = GlobalScope,
    request: MFSendPaymentRequest,
    apiLang: String,
    listener: (MFResult<MFSendPaymentResponse>) -> Unit
) {
    Const.apiLang = apiLang

    coroutineScope?.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        val dataResource = networkBoundResource {
            mInteractors.sendPayment(request)
        }

        when (dataResource) {
            is MFResult.Success ->
                listener.invoke(MFResult.Success(dataResource.value.response!!))
            is MFResult.Fail ->
                listener.invoke(MFResult.Fail(dataResource.error))
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the test class:**

```
class MFSDKMainTest {

private val mfSDKPaymentRepository = mock<MFSDKPaymentGateWay>()
private val testScope = TestCoroutineScope()

@get:Rule
val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

@Before
fun setup() {
    Dispatchers.setMain(Dispatchers.Unconfined)
}

@After
fun tearDown() {
    Dispatchers.resetMain()
    testScope.cleanupTestCoroutines()
}

@Test
fun testCallSendPayment() = runBlockingTest {
    val data = MFSendPaymentResponse(invoiceId = ID)
    val expectedResponse = SDKSendPaymentResponse(data)

    val request = MFSendPaymentRequest(
        0.100,
        "Customer name",
        MFNotificationOption.LINK
    )
    val lang = MFAPILanguage.EN

    whenever(mfSDKPaymentRepository.sendPayment(request))
        .thenReturn(expectedResponse)

    MFSDKMain.callSendPayment(testScope, request, lang) {
        assert(it is MFResult.Success)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your function when you call

```
mInteractors.sendPayment(request)
```

how do you get a refrence to `MFSDKPaymentGateWay`? In your test method you are not setting the mocked object in `MFSDKMain` class.

If you are creating it inside the  same class (which i assume is an Object class) you may need to find a way to mock object class. Probably you need to use [mockk](https://mockk.io/) instead of mockito

If you have setter method for `MFSDKPaymentGateWay` you should call it in your test method.